# How to know torch version that installed locally in your device

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, torch

I want to check torch version in my device using Jupyter Notebook.

I'm used this

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

but it didn't work and Jupyter notebook raised an error as below

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-beb55f24d5ec> in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 print(torch.__version__)

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Is there any command to check torch version using Jupyter notebook?

Comment: According to [this PyTorch form](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-know-the-current-version-of-pytorch/6754/5) make sure that you have the right version of python. If you're running python from `python` switch it to `python3` and vice versa.

Comment: I am using `Python 3.7.9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I have tried to install new Pytorch version. But, it didn't work and then I deleted the Pytorch files manually suggested on my command line. Finally, I installed new Pytorch version using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch` and everything works fine.

This code works well after that.

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Open your terminal

```sh
python3 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check list all installed python modules with version tag via [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).

To ensure running the proper pip version, just execute it via the python interpreter:

```
# python symlink
python -m pip freeze
# python3
python3 -m pip freeze
```

You can grep for the module of question (used numpy as an example)

```
python -m pip freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.19.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If in the terminal, use pip.

```
user@debian:~/..$ pip3 show torch
Name: torch
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/
Author: PyTorch Team
Author-email: packages@pytorch.org
License: BSD-3
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by: torchaudio, torchvision
```